# Is it possible to have my app accessible from the iphone lock screen the same way *Medical Id is available?

Tags: iphone, lockscreen, lockscreenwidget

I want to know if it is possible for my app to display information to the user EVEN if they haven't unlocked their iphone lock screen.   I want it to act similar to the way the Medical ID information can be displayed (if enabled) on a locked iphone.

Comment: No, there is no API that will allow this.